# Generic S3 function for multiple classes

Tags: r

I have a generic function like this:

```
convert <- function(x) UseMethod("simplifyResultConvert")

convert.default <- function(x) {
  x
}

convert.POSIXct <- function(x) {
  as.character(x)
}

convert.factor <- function(x) {
  as.character(x)
}

convert.Date <- function(x) {
  as.character(x)
}
```

Is there any way to simplify it by making one generic for type: POSIXct, Date and factor?

To make it clear: I need something like:

```
convert.(POSIXct || factor || date) <- funciton(x) {as.character(x)}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Right now I interpret it as you wanting one (non-default) **method** for several classes. This is not possible with S3 if there is no super-class.

Comment: yes, this is whaa I was asking for. for example: `convert.(POSIXct || factor || date) <- funciton(x) {as.character(x)}`. Is it possible with S4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a test of the class in the default method, for example:

```
convert.default <- function(x) {
  if (inherits(x, "POSIXct") ||
      inherits(x, "factor") ||
      inherits(x, "Date"))
    as.character(x)
  else
    x
}
```

This is not quite the same as what you want, because an object could have class `c("POSIXct", "other")` and if there was a `convert.other()` method set, it would be called instead of the default.

If you really want the behaviour you asked for, you need the three functions, but you can save a bit of typing by using

```
convert.Date <- convert.factor <- convert.POSIXct <- function(x) {
  as.character(x)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Write it like this:

```
convert.default <- function(x) x

convert.Date <-     
convert.factor <- 
convert.POSIXct <- function(x) as.character(x)
```

A further simplification would be:

```
convert.default <- identity

convert.Date <-     
convert.factor <- 
convert.POSIXct <- as.character
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no super-classes in S3, this is not possible with S3. However, you can easily do this with S4 which allows defining super-classes:

```
setGeneric("convert", function(object) {
  standardGeneric("convert")
})

setClassUnion("fooClasses", members = c("factor", "Date", "POSIXt")) #POSIXt is a super-class
setMethod("convert", signature(object = "fooClasses"), function(object) {
  as.character(object)
})

class(convert(as.Date("2010-10-10")))
#[1] "character"
class(convert(as.POSIXct("2010-10-10")))
#[1] "character"
```